Issues with NGINX Configuration as a Reverse Proxy for a React-Vite Application
Problem Description:
I am working on a React application using Vite, and I am running it in a Docker container. I use a Dockerfile to build and serve the application, and I also have an nginx.cfg configuration file for NGINX to act as a reverse proxy and provide HTTPS access.
• Dockerfile:
# Build stage
FROM node:18-alpine AS build

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json to install dependencies
COPY package*.json ./

# Install project dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy the rest of the project files
COPY . .

# Build the application
RUN npm run build

# Production stage
FROM node:18-alpine

WORKDIR /app

# Install serve globally
RUN npm install -g serve

# Copy only the build folder
COPY --from=build /app/dist ./dist

EXPOSE 97

CMD ["serve", "-s", "dist", "-l", "97"]


• nginx.cfg:
events {
    worker_connections 1024;  # Maximum number of connections accepted by each worker
}

http {
    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name my_domain_here;
        http2 on;
        
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl_certificate.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl_certificate.key;

        location /photo/ {
            proxy_pass http://prueba_front:97/photo/;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_read_timeout 90s;
            proxy_connect_timeout 90s;
            proxy_send_timeout 90s;
            send_timeout 90s;
        }
    }
}

docker-compose.yml
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.cfg:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./ssl:/etc/nginx/ssl
    networks:
      - poc_probe

  prueba_front:
    build:
      context: ./app/front
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "97:97"
    networks:
      - poc_probe

networks:
  poc_probe:
    driver: bridge

• vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// Desarrollo
export default defineConfig({
  base: "/",  // Base URL para la aplicación
  plugins: [react()],
  build: {
    outDir: 'dist', // Directorio de salida para la construcción
    rollupOptions: {
      // Configuración adicional de Rollup si es necesaria
    }
  },
  preview: {
    port: 5173,
    strictPort: true,
  },
  server: {
    port: 5173,
    strictPort: true,
    host: true,
    origin: "http://0.0.0.0:8080",
  },
});


Problem Description:
When I try to access https://my_domain/photo/, I receive an error indicating that the static .js and .css files in the dist folder cannot be found. However, when I enter the container running on port 97, I can see that the files are present.
error image
Error in the https
I have tried accessing the application using my private IP, and it works correctly, but when using the reverse proxy with HTTPS, I encounter the aforementioned error.
Question:
What could be wrong with the NGINX configuration that prevents the static files from being served correctly through the reverse proxy? Is there any way to debug this issue?
I verified that the static files are indeed generated in the dist folder when I build the application. I attempted to configure NGINX to serve these files through the reverse proxy, but I have not been successful in getting it to work as expected. I am quite new to using NGINX, so I may have overlooked something in the configuration.
I was expecting to access the static files via https://my_domain/photo/, and for them to be served correctly without any errors.
